# Running F# Hello World from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, launcher

I ran the canonical F# Hello World program by

```
dotnet run
```

It works. Now, I want to run it from VS Code, pushing F5 from the editor window showing Program.fs . In launch.json I have

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/HelloWorld.dll",
```

where HelloWorld is the project directory which is a child of the directory where the solution file resides. This file exists.

Upon hitting F5 I get

> Could not find the task 'build'.

How can I configure VS Code to run my F# program with F5?

Answer (score 3):

A search for

> tasks.json f#

revealed

https://forums.fsharp.org/t/how-to-set-up-f-development-in-visual-studio-code/1125/2

and that answers my question: when the dialog box with the

> Could not find the task 'build'.

message pops up, I should choose

> Configure Task

and in the pop down window

> Create tasks.json file from template

and then the

> .NET Core

template. Afterwards, F5 works to build and run the F# program.